# Really weird "UTF-8" code

Tags: python, csv, database, utf-8

I downloaded a database from imdb in the form of a tsv.gz (csv) file. Imdb said that the file was in UTF-8 (https://www.imdb.com/interfaces/?ref_=login), but when I looked at the file in NotePad and in Excel, it was a bunch of Chinese letters/symbols, so I'm assuming I cannot use it in Python. Does anyone know what happened or what to do?

Comment: Hey there, welcome to Superuser! Consider adding some specific steps you took to open the file to help you get the best answer. For example, you made a reference to opening the file with python. Could you expand your answer to include which methods or libraries you might have used? The more specific you can be on your steps up until now, the faster someone will be able to understand your exact issue. Also, consider providing links to where "Imdb said that the file was in UTF-8..." so people can have a look at the references you're using. :)

Comment: I added the link, but I did not try to read it in Python because it seems useless, and there are so many lines of data that I don't want to waste time. Also thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for that added detail.

That file you've downloaded is compressed using *gzip* and if you try to view it as-is, it'll get interpreted as those characters you're seeing. You'll need to *unpack* it before you can view the text in Notepad or Excel.

As Dave mentions below, you should be able to make use of any number of zip/archiving tool to unzip it. You might also want to google "unpack .gz file on windows" and follow the steps.

Once unpacked, you should get a file with **.tsv** extension like IMBD indicates.

If you've already unpacked the **.gz** file and you're still seeing odd characters, you may not simply need to *open* the file but *import* it into Excel. For that, see the [following guide](http://www.arj.no/2013/06/28/how-to-import-tsv-file-in-ms-excel/).

Hope that helps! Feel free to comment with your progress.

Comment: No, it's not a tar. As the imdb page says, and the extension .tsv.gz indicates, it's a TSV file compressed with gzip. Any file can be processed with gzip (although some will not actually get shorter, so it's silly to do them) and while it's common to gzip files that are actually archives in tar format, it's also common to gzip other kinds of files. WinZip can indeed uncompress any .gz not just .tar.gz, and I believe 7zip also, and Excel can indeed open the (uncompressed) TSV -- if you have enough memory, because these files are large.

Comment: Oops! Right you are Dave. That’s just a mistake on my part but I imagine the underlying problem is the same and that an initial uncompressing is necessary before importing the file to Excel. I’ll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded and used title.ratings.tsv.gz. There is no problem.

These the steps, to open it:

- uncompress it (if you are a win user, you can use 7zip utility);
- than simply open it.

If you use Excel you must use import process (http://www.arj.no/2013/06/28/how-to-import-tsv-file-in-ms-excel/).

In NotePad it appears is in this way

[image]